# Smooth Streaming Codec Private Data

Tags: format, streaming, smoothing, smooth-streaming

When I add a new `SSF_STREAM_INFO` into the SSF SDK muxer, the header data that is produced doesn't seem to contain a proper value for `CodecPrivateData` param.

`<param name="CodecPrivateData" value="0000000100000001" valuetype="data" />`

I am under the impression that this information is used by a smooth streaming player, to decode individual frames. See, when I play back my live stream from my encoder I get a blank frames in my video feed.

If `CodecPrivateData` is supposed to contain information on decoding frames, how do I properly set it and with what data? Pretty sure that belongs in the `MPEG2VIDEOINFO` struct (that I use for the stream info's `pTypeSpecificInfo` field).

Below is more of the header information that the muxer produces. Does any one have any experience with this? Some pointers would be helpful!

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language">
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <switch>
            <video src="Streams" systemBitrate="500000">
                <param name="trackID" value="1" valuetype="data" />
                <param name="FourCC" value="AVC1" valueType="data" />
                <param name="MaxWidth" value="320" valueType="data" />
                <param name="MaxHeight" value="240" valueType="data" />
                <param name="CodecPrivateData" value="0000000100000001" valuetype="data" />
            </video>
        </switch>
    </body>
</smil>`
```

My encoder is encoding a live h.264 video feed into the SSF muxer. So I used an `MPEG2VIDEOINFO` struct for my `pTypeSpecificInfo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The codec private data for AVC1 is supposed to be

**NAL_START_CODE SPS NAL_START_CODE PPS**

where

**NAL_START_CODE** is the byte sequence 00,00,00,01

**SPS** is Sequence Parameter Set, and

**PPS** is Picture Parameter Set

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728116%28v=vs.95%29.aspx